# Conceptual confusion about numerical methods

Tags: numerical-methods

I have a conceptual question about numerical methods. What is the difference among finite element, continuous finite element, discontinuous finite element, continuous galerkin and discontinuous galerkin methods?  Are some of them just the same thing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finite element methods are a subset of numerical methods (which also include finite volume, finite difference, Monte Carlo and a *lot* more).

Simply put, in finite element methods, one tries to approximate the solution to a problem with a linear combination of pre-defined basis functions. These basis functions can be chosen to be either continuous or discontinuous. The resulting numerical methods are called CG/[DG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_Galerkin_method) (continuous/discontinuous Galerkin) methods. In a DG method, the basis functions are only *piecewise* continuous: each basis function is zero everywhere in the domain, except in one element. See also this [excellent Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method), which features some very nice figures.

Discontinuous Garlerkin methods were originally popularised in the field of particle transport long ago, but they have recently gained ground in other fields as well. (This is mostly because it wasn't clear at first how discontinuous basis functions would work well in equations that involve diffusion, but that problem has been solved now.)

Comment: Thanks @A.Hennik for the nice detailed explanation :)  So if I understand you correctly when we are talking about "continuous FE method" and "continuous Galerkin method" we are talking about the same thing i.e continuous basis functions used to approximate the solution, is that right? Same applies for "discontinuous FE" and "discontinuous Galerkin" they are basically the same thing ?

Comment: Yes. Every paper I found that has "(dis)continuous finite element" in the title basically uses it as a synonym for "(dis)continuous Galerkin". The term "Galerkin method" can be used a bit more generally for several problems that are formulated with a so-called *weak form*, as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerkin_method). (I just love Wikipedia when it comes to math.) I don't believe the details are very relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small pedantic correction to @A. Hennink's answer - In DG methods, the state variable is *not* piece-wise continuous between basis functions. There is a non-physical jump in the state variable between basis functions, hence the discontinuous part in the name. This can be visualized in the following figure displaying (dis)continuous basis functions of CG and DG:

[image: Discontinuity in DG vs CG]

In CG methods, the basis functions are piece-wise continuous, meaning continuous in the state variable itself, but the derivative may not be continuous (i.e. there may be a discontinuity in the derivative of the state variable between basis functions). This means that the solution to what ever problem you're solving can have non-physical kinks in the solution. Note the 'kinks' in the following solution

[image: Piece-wise continuous FEM]

Some basis functions are not always discontinuous in the derivative though (see Hermite basis functions). See how the following Hermite basis function has a derivative of zero at both the end points. If all basis functions are composed using Hermite polynomials, then the derivative is continuous between basis functions because it's zero at the boundaries. Below, Psi_1 is the derivate of Psi_0, and Psi_3 is the derivative of Psi_2:

[image]